# como definir ultima tradução usada pelo usuario na plataforma

Tags: laravel

Tenho uma plataforma com 6 idiomas diferentes e preciso manter o último idioma selecionado para o usuário na plataforma, mas não sei como fazer isso, como posso fazer?

por exemplo:

se o usuário utilizar a plataforma em francês por último, quando ele fizer login novamente, a plataforma deverá permanecer em francês

5.8 lavável

Answer (score 1):

Salva um cache com o login do usuário quando ele muda o idioma, por exemplo

```
Cache::put(auth()->user()->username.'_lang', $linguaEscolhida);
```

Então implementa um middleware que defina a língua para cada requisição do usuário, por exemplo o método handle do middleware seria:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->check()) {
        $lang = Cache::get(auth()->user()->username.'_lang', config('app.locale'));
        App::setLocale($lang);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

No exemplo se o usuário está autenticado então recupera do cache sua entrada para a língua escolhida, ou retorna o locale padrão configurado na aplicação caso não exista um cache para o usuário.

Na sequência define o locale com o App::setLocale